# SOLVED - How to import a text file with "," value to Mysql

Tags: mysql, import

I have data in a text file that have value like this :

```
  _______________________________________
  |id|name_item                   |value|
  _______________________________________
  | 1|Luas Bangunan               | 200 |
  | 2|Listrik, Air dan Air Bersih | 300 |
  | 3|Akademik (S1,D1,dan D3)     | 100 |
  _______________________________________
```

I've already try to import it to mysql and save it as csv but the result is :

```
  _____________________________________________________
  |id|name_item                   |value               |
  ______________________________________________________
  | 1|Luas Bangunan               | 200                |
  | 2|Listrik                     | Air dan Air Bersih |
  | 3|Akademik (S1                | D1,dan D3)         |
  ______________________________________________________
```

Anyone, How to solve this?

Update : I've already got the solution for this topic, I change "," delimiter to pipe delimiter.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: I think that you're going to somehow place double quotes into your file - maybe using sed (or Windows equivalent) or get your data feed to be with pipes (|).

Comment: What tool are you using to import?

Comment: @Phil I use mysql front and openoffice

Comment: With what options?  What does the data file look like?